# Storing sqlalchemy mapped objects in cache

Tags: python, mysql, session, caching, sqlalchemy

I have some environment with very old python (2.5) and corresponding libraries (eg sqlalchemy 0.5.2).
There are some alchemy models in my project. I often select them, rarely update. So I have two engines, one to master, other to slave. My model has method save(self, session), which I use to store changes in database.

Other code selects objects from db by primary key, on each pk it checks, if it has mapped objects in cache, if not it selects row from db via s.query method, pickles mapped object and put into cache (memcache in my case, but it doesn't matter). If it is already in cache, just unpickle it from cache, do session.merge and returns.
After each self.save call I invalidate cache for current instance and do one selection, to precache it, so I have always actual objects in cache.

If I didn't do session.merge calls I would have exception on each attribute resolving if I would get object from cache in another process (or in this process after restart):

```
/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py in __get__(self, instance, owner)
157         if instance is None:
158             return self
--> 159         return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance))
160
161 class _ProxyImpl(object):
```

But using session.merge cause an update query, which negates using memcache at all - just instead of selection I do update. And it fails, when I use session binded to read-only engine.

How should I properly store SqlAlchemy orm mapped objects in serialized state, without references to storage - memcache, file-based, in-ram etc - and without extra update queries to db?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has resolved by disabling autoflush and autocommit for each session. So, read-only session never sends any modification queries,  and read-write session send only explicitly changed rows.